# What should I do to pass the 404 failure for a WebAPI with Azure Identity?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I created a **WebAPI** in **Visual Studio 2019 Preview** and selected **Azure Identity** for the authentication. When I run the API, I get a **Not Authorized** 404 error.

This is what I see in the `appsettings.json` file.

What should I do to in **Azure Portal** to fix the 401 error?

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "myemailmycompany.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-dcbeeeac82d9",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-ac3f-9a785f72fd83"
  }
```

Comment: The error code you encountered should be 401, am I right?

Comment: My suggestion is written in the answer, you can try it out, if you need to deploy to azure, you need to set the `Authentication` on the portal. Hope it helps you.

Comment: I wonder if your problem is solved? Does my answer help you? If there is a better way to solve this problem, you can also send your own answers, which can better help others in the forum.

Answer (score 0):

I used the **APP ID URI** from the Azure Portal in the **ClientID** in **appsettings.son** instead of the GUID to get authenticated.

Answer (score -1):

you can't just run the project like that, as you don't have an authentication token or anything since its a web API.

you may want to start here, as i'm not sure what client you are using but this is a good example. 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/1.%20Desktop%20app%20calls%20Web%20API

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/calling-an-aspnet-core-web-api-from-a-wpf-application-using-azure-ad-v2/

Comment: The point of the problem is not this, u can use the demo code in `App registrations`, it works. But that version of dotnet core is 2.0, this post just create a project then use ad authentication.